# Recover Deleted Installation Row

Tags: android, parsing, parse-platform

To enforce uniqueness of installation row (for an android app) in case of re-installation or clearing app data we created a code snippet in beforeSave hook to delete previous rows on the basis of android id.

Due to some bug we accidentally deleted few hundreds of installation rows. These rows are not being recreated as it is treated as an update request rather than create request.
 We have tried a couple of workaround like 
 
1 .setting current installation id to null

 2. subscribing to a channel(it seems to work intermittently)

 3.trying to unpin installation object

4. trying to delete installation row using delete command

Please suggest whats the best and reliable way to recreate or recover those rows either from android side or from cloud side

Comment: It's pretty hard to guess without seeing code.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid deleting any rows from the Installation table. Every time a user clean installs your app a new row will be created for them and you simply need to associate their user (if you have any) with that row and forget about the previous zombie rows in the Installation table.

Recovering installation rows you lost will not be straightforward given that your current Installation object on any device now has an associated `objectId` which does not exist on the server and therefore you cannot update it any more. You might be able to access the values within current installation object on your devices, construct a new Installation object and save that in the Installation table again with a new `objectId`. Then somehow synchronise your invalid `current` Installation object with the newly created object you saved. I would say this is quite fiddly but might work.